# "Inverted" SQL SELECT - Find staff who didn't make cold calls between a date range

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I've gotten my brain in a bit of a muddle. Here is my SQL statement to **select all staff who DID make cold calls between a date and time**:

```
SELECT staff.name
FROM staff

JOIN staff_prospects ON staff_prospects.staff_id = staff.id
JOIN staff_prospect_activity ON staff_prospect_activity.prospect_id = staff_prospects.id

WHERE DATE_FORMAT(staff_prospect_activity.date_of_activity, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2013-05-31" AND "2013-05-31"

GROUP BY staff.name
```

That will list all staff names who have cold-called a prospect. **But I need to 'invert' this query so it gets all staff who didn't, between the same date range.**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would DATE() do instead of DATE_FORMAT()?

Answer (score 3):

use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.name
FROM    staff a
        INNER JOIN staff_prospects b
            ON b.staff_id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN staff_prospect_activity c
            ON  c.prospect_id = b.id AND
                c.date_of_activity >= '2013-05-31' AND 
                c.date_of_activity < '2013-05-31' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
WHERE   c.prospect_id IS NULL
GROUP   BY a.name
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce the desired results. It only returns names of staff who don't have any prospects at all. Staff could have many prospects (or none) and many prospect activities (or none), I just want to return names of those who don't have any prospect activity today.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get 0 rows. I know for certain there are staff who haven't made cold calls in this date range.

Comment: can you give sample records? i just tested this with my own set of records an it works.

Comment: If the data is "unusual" and the `staff_prospect` table has nullable `id` column this may not work.

Comment: try `where c.id IS NULL` instead of `b.id`

Comment: @DaveTurvey maybe you mean `c.prospect_id`?

Answer (score 2):

Use NOT EXISTS. Something like that should work:

```
SELECT staff.name
FROM staff

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM staff_prospects 
JOIN staff_prospect_activity ON staff_prospect_activity.prospect_id = staff_prospects.id
WHERE staff_prospects.staff_id = staff.id AND
DATE_FORMAT(staff_prospect_activity.date_of_activity, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2013-05-31" AND "2013-05-31")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT staff.name
FROM staff

INNER JOIN staff_prospects 
ON staff_prospects.staff_id = staff.id
LEFT JOIN staff_prospect_activity 
ON staff_prospect_activity.prospect_id = staff_prospects.id

WHERE DATE_FORMAT(staff_prospect_activity.date_of_activity, "%Y-%m-%d") BETWEEN "2013-    05-01" AND "2013-05-31" AND STAFF_PROSPECT_ACTIVITY.prospect_id IS NULL

GROUP BY staff.name
```

(Your dates were the same 5/31/2013 and 5/31/2013. Unless you just want one date.) Also use left join and check for null values.