# How to create a sql view that excludes based on datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a view that produces employees who do not have an entry on a particular day , my schema :

```
employee_master:
employee_id (int)
employee_name (varchar)

employee_time:
employee_id (int)
employee_start_tm (datetime)
employee_end_tm (datetime)
```

the following sql statement lists all employees who **do** have entry on a particular date:

```
select employee_master.employee_name  , employee_time.employee_start_tm 
from  employee_master inner join on employee_master.employee_id  = employee_time.employee_id;
```

I want the opposite of this, employees who do not have entries ?

Comment: You might consider the `right join` type of table connection.

Comment: Replace your description of the table with the actual CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all employees that don't have any entries on `2013-05-31` you can do

```
select m.employee_name
from  employee_master m
inner join employee_time t on t.employee_id  = m.employee_id
group by m.employee_name
having sum('2013-05-31' between employee_start_tm and employee_end_tm) = 0
```

Comment: this query is returning zero results. Also I have datetime not just date

Comment: I used `count` instead of  `sum`. Corrected that. [Simplyfied SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf2e5b/9)

Answer (score 0):

Use NOT EXISTS or NOT IN statements. For example:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_MASTER.EMPLOYEE_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE_MASTER
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TIME WHERE EMPLOYEE_TIME.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE_MASTER.EMPLOYEE_ID)
```

Quite similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854329/inverted-sql-select-find-staff-who-didnt-make-cold-calls-between-a-date-ran)

Comment: I need this statement for a particular date. if you add the start time to the query it will not return any results.

Comment: Just add the statement in the inner query, like this(replace REQUIRED_DATE with the desired value):    SELECT EMPLOYEE_MASTER.EMPLOYEE_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE_MASTER
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TIME WHERE EMPLOYEE_TIME.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMPLOYEE_MASTER.EMPLOYEE_ID AND REQUIRED_DATE BETWEEN EMPLOYEE_TIME.employee_start_tm AND EMPLOYEE_TIME.employee_end_tm)